# How to detect the IE Mobile browser using HTML conditional statements WITHOUT using JavaScript?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, mobile-website, ie-mobile

Is there any way to detect the IE Mobile browser using HTML conditional statements **WITHOUT using JavaScript**?

`[if IE]>` check is not working for mobile IE

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <div class="iemobile-support" >
        ATTENTION: We have detected that you are using Internet Explorer on your device.
    </div>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional comments are only supported in IE 5-9.

[Source](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

Another fix is that you can write IE conditional css to hide or show the div.

CSS :

```
    <style>
        .iemobile-support{ display:none; }

        @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) { 
             /* IE10+ specific styles go here */  
           .iemobile-support{ display:block; } 
        }
    </style>

    <!--[if IE]>
        <style>
            .iemobile-support{ display:block; }
        </style>
    <![endif]-->
```

HTML :

```
    <div class="iemobile-support" >
        ATTENTION: We have detected that you are using Internet Explorer on your device.
    </div>
```

Comment: its for IEMobile not the Desktop IE

Comment: Did you try this fix on IEMobile?